# In Reactjs, how can i pass two props with one of them is array

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass two props to a child component  like this:

```
<CountData onchoiceChange={[{value: 1, label: A}]} selectedGroup ={"GrpA"} />
```

And since onchoiceChange is an jsonarray it could be something like:

```
[{value: 1, label: A},{value: 2, label: B}]
```

and if i pass props like the above ,
in my child functional component

```
export default function CountData(onchoiceChange,selectedGroup) {
```

my value become

-onchoiceChange.onchoiceChange
-onchoiceChange.selectedGroup

and my desired is only
-onchoiceChange &
-selectedGroup

thank if anyone can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your component is receiving a single parameter, which is an object containing the props of your component. Hence, you can destructure it like this, to access the object you want:

```
export default function CountData({onchoiceChange,selectedGroup}) { ... }
```

You can also destructure the props object in an other way, which is equivalent, more verbose, but easyer to understand:

```
export default function CountData(props)   {
    const {onchoiceChange,selectedGroup} = props
}
```

If the way how props are working in React is not clear for you, I suggest you to read the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

And if you want to know more about destructuration, you can read this [article](https://medium.com/@lcriswell/destructuring-props-in-react-b1c295005ce0) for instance.